# When I want to install mysql on my fedora 35 I get an error with conflicting requests

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora

Hello I am trying to install mysql on my Fedora 35 machine. I followed the guid from one [forum](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-8-on-fedora/) . But I am getting an error and don't know how to solve.

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package mysql-community-server-8.0.27-10.fc35.x86_64 requires mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 8.0.11, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mysql-community-server-8.0.28-10.fc35.x86_64 requires mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 8.0.11, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mysql-community-client-8.0.27-10.fc35.x86_64 requires mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 8.0.11, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mysql-community-client-8.0.28-10.fc35.x86_64 requires mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 8.0.11, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mysql-community-libs-8.0.27-10.fc35.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package mysql-community-libs-8.0.28-10.fc35.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Comment: You could try installing mariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

When installing mysql on Fedora 35 just type this from the terminal.

sudo dnf install mysql-server